# How to update item in Model array in different scopes, and have changes reflect everywhere?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a parent `$scope` and child `$scope`. When the child view is loaded, I make a `GET` call to retrieve `JSON` data (an array of hundreds of objects), which I then pass to the parent `$scope`.

Now in the `child` view I retrieve data from the `parent`'s `model` to get what I need to build widgets with `ng-repeat`. In each widget there is data(a select dropdown) and a edit button which opens up a modal which lives in the parent view.

---

***My issue:***
I need to pull the exact selected object data `model` into the modal and editing the data in the modal should reflect changes everywhere. Inside the modal as well as in the `ng-repeat` in the child.

---

[image]

Init object in the Parent to contain the Array of Objects:

```
// Model to contain the items:
var itemsModel = {};
```

A call from the Controller inside the Child on view load:

```
// Inside Child view:
// The GET to retrieve items
ItemFactory.getAllItems(byProduct).then(function(data) {

    // I set the Model in the parent to the data
    $scope.main.itemsModel = data.data.items;

    // In child scope I now setup the ng-repeat
    vm.items = $scope.main.itemsModel;
    vm.totalItems = $scope.main.itemsModel.length;

});
```

Example of part of an `object` in the `Array` that comes back from the `GET`

```
{
    tag: "kitchen",
    term: "Red",
    item_id: "99312"
}
```

HTML of the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="item in child.items" class="col-md-6">

<section class="bg-placeholder" value="{{item.item}}">

    <!-- Here is the function to open up the modal in the parent scope -->
    <a href="" ng-click="child.openTagModal(item.item_id, item.item)">
        <div ng-model="child.itemName" class="tag">
            {{item.item}}
        </div>
    </a>

    <div class="item-dropdown">

        <!-- ng-change here detects a change and sends a PUT request -->
        <select ng-model="item.chosenTag"
                ng-change="child.updateTag(item)">

            <option value="companies"
                    ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'kitchen'}}"
                    changed="kitchen">kitchen</option>

            <option value="bedroom"
                    ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'bedroom'}}"
                    changed="bedroom">bedroom</option>
            ...
```

Finally the function in the Child that opens the modal that lives in the Parent, here I'm stuck as to how to pass the exact data I need to it, so that any changes in their reflect in the ng-repeat as well.

```
vm.openItemModal = function(id, item) {

    console.log(id);
    console.log(item);

    $scope.main.itemId = id;
    $scope.main.product = item;

    // Shows the modal
    $scope.main.modal_item = true;
    $scope.main.modal = true;
```

The HTML in the model that lives in the Parent

```
<select ng-model="main.tag"
        ng-change="main.updateTag(id, item)"
        class="btn-default">

    <option value="kitchen"
            ng-selected="{{main.tag == 'kitchen'}}"
            changed="kitchen">kitchen</option>

    <option value="bedroom"
            ng-selected="{{main.tag == 'bedroom'}}"
            changed="bedroom">bedroom</option>
```

Right now editing the item tag in the Parent model will update the item's data on the Database, but it doesn't change the data that lives in the Child scope, the ng-repeat.

```
vm.updateTag = function(id, tag, item) {

    // PUT to update the object data in the Database:
    ItemFactory.updateTag(
        id,
        tag,
        item).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**
 Created a new Factory service to handle updating the model, however still can't update the Child tag scope which is inside the ng-repeat FROM the Parent scope:
[How to update model on select inside of ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152443/how-to-update-model-on-select-inside-of-ng-repeat)

---

Comment: What do you think of sending a $scope.emit('message', data) to the parent scope?

Comment: Oh didn't even know about `broadcast` and `emit` thanks checking this out, but is this what you would use in this case? So that editing the data in the parent modal will make a change reflect in the child ng-repeat widget?

Comment: I have a case like yours at my work and we use the emit and broadcast to make the communication beetween controllers. Just keep in mind that you should use them with caution because if you put too many events you might have some performance issues. Another question. You must propagate that to the siblings too, not only the parent right?

Comment: better you can maintain one service that will share data..

Comment: @pankajparkar ok so I use my *ApiFactory*, to `GET` the JSON array... send it into the `Model` in the `Parent`, then use an *ItemFactory* to make changes?

Comment: I think you factory will be like, you will one variable in it, then there will be two method getter and setter for that variable, then you can make one copy of data in your service

Comment: @pankajparkar you guys mind taking a look at this? I refactored my calls to update a tag model inside of a new Service, but I still can't change the child model http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152443/how-to-update-model-on-select-inside-of-ng-repeat

Comment: @LeonGaban can you please check my answer, how I did maintain one single variable which will contains the data, you haven't did that in your service which you had created.https://gist.github.com/leongaban/2d58174cfe6e5c9c0465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you problem I'd like to resolve this issue by create a factory which will be sharable in all controllers

```
app.service('sharableService',[ function(){
   this.sharableData = {};
   //getter
   this.getData = function(){
      return this.sharableData;
   }
   //setter
   this.setData = function(value){
      this.sharableData = value;
   }
}]);
```

OR

**Factory**

```
app.factory('sharableService',[ function(){
   var sharableData = {};
   //getter
   var getData = function(){
      return sharableData;
   }
   //setter
   var setData = function(value){
      sharableData = value;
   }
   //method are exposed.
   return {
      getData: getData,
      setData: setData
   }
}]);
```

This sharable service can be use full to share data between controllers.

Comment: Thanks man :) you pointed me in the right direction, I did go with the Factory.... also I needed to make sure that my `ng-model` on the selects were correct: Child `<select ng-model="term.tag"` Parent `<select ng-model="main.the_tag.tag"` `the_tag`

Comment: @LeonGaban yeahh Thanks.. I saw your factory..there is lot of re factoring needed..and I'm curious to know why you didn't maintain a variable in factory which has all tags data?

Comment: I did have this inside of the tagFactory: `var tags = {};` then my `tags.setTagsModel` function to set the tags inside the Factory.

Comment: no that is what you did wrong.. give me 5 mins I'll refactor it

Comment: @LeonGaban see here http://pastebin.com/pEG7CKBL basically you mixed service and factory together..try to get it work..