# How to update model on select inside of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

The widget inside the Child scope, with the ng-repeated div and select dropdown:

```
<div ng-repeat="term in ticker.terms">
    <select ng-model="term.chosenTag" ng-change="ticker.changeTag(term)">
        <option>...</option>
        <option>...</option>
        <option>...</option>
```

---

I'm trying to change ^ **term.chosenTag** from the parent scope, `term` is the repeated data object (`term in terms`)

---

**Full code Gists:**
Main Parent HTML:
 https://gist.github.com/leongaban/e0154005bed6b6892df7

Ticker Child HTML
https://gist.github.com/leongaban/9a5fd86643051fd9e1af

TickerController (Child)
https://gist.github.com/leongaban/2d58174cfe6e5c9c0465

MainController (Parent)
https://gist.github.com/leongaban/1563b09b906337a3e6ad

TagFactory
https://gist.github.com/leongaban/8db5027e1cb86f614fa5

---

Now the select in the parent scope that needs to also control the model in the child select:

```
<select ng-model="main.selected_tag"
        ng-change="main.changeTag(main.the_tag)">
```

That main.changeTag function calls this:

```
vm.changeTag = function(term) {

    // Update tag in model:
    TagFactory.updateTag(term);
};
```

TagFactory then updates the term on the database as well as my model:

```
// Update tag:
tags.updateTag = function(data) {
    var tag = data;

    // Filter and find tag by id:
    var tagObj = {};
    tagObj = $filter('filter')(tags, { term_id: tag.term_id })[0];

    // Update tag in model:
    tagObj.tag = tag.chosenTag;

    /**
    * PUT : update tag on DB
    */
    ApiFactory.updateTag(
        tag.term_id,
        tag.chosenTag,
        tag.ticker).then(function(data) {
            console.log('PUT:');
            console.log(data);
    });

    return tag;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Are you trying to maintain state between parent and child scopes?

Comment: I made a new service which maintains a Model that is shared between scopes. My problem is, How do I update this: `term.chosenTag` which is inside of `term in terms`? I can't target and change that from the Parent. I'm going to post my entire new Factory.

Comment: I would make the "tags" variable from TagFactory accessible from outside (if it isn't), then I would repeat over a $scope variable that points to TagFactory.tags (either directly or with a function call). If you do that, your ng-model is directly accessing the appropriate object in TagFactory. I consider this way fairly "angular".

Comment: I need an example please... how would I repeat the ng-repeat? I only do that on the child view load? I mean if I could refresh the page that would solve my problem. But trying to do this in a single page app way and not do a refresh.

Comment: @LeonGaban I don't see you have created any variable which will contain all tags..you had added just getter and setter

Comment: @pankajparkar `vm.terms = TagFactory.getTagsModel();` btw I'm going to post links to all my code in a sec

Comment: @pankajparkar Here is my TagFactory https://gist.github.com/leongaban/8db5027e1cb86f614fa5 and TickerController https://gist.github.com/leongaban/2d58174cfe6e5c9c0465

Comment: does you issue is resolved?

Comment: @pankajparkar yes using a Factory service to organize my Model data in 1 place. And also making sure that my `ng-models` where set correctly did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you fire your updateTag call onchange, as opposed to onclick, I am going to assume that constantly updating the service's data is OK. The other method where this wouldn't be advisable is if you only want to push data to the service at certain times, to avoid all your templates from seeing the changes to the factory data immediately if you still need to execute AJAX.

In the appropriate controller, with TagFactory injected, create a reference to the factory's data:

```
$scope.tags = TagFactory.tags;
```

Then your HTML can directly modify the TagFactory itself:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in /*expression that determines ticker.terms with respect to $scope.tags*/">
    <select ng-model="tag.chosenTag">
```

The expression can be as simple as "tags", but it will probably need to involve a filter that only returns tags that are ticker.terms.

Comment: I've got 100s of tags though... this would work if I only had 1 tag correct? I'm going to post full code in Gists, I don't think my problem is being shown here best.

Comment: As I said, you will probably need to filter the tags with respect to "ticker". You will essentially want "tag in tags | filter" to be identical to "ticker.terms" once the filter has been processed. I should be able to figure out how to accomplish that once the gist is posted.

Comment: Ah dude, I didn't need a filter.. but I need to make sure my `ng-models` where synced up correctly! Child: `<select ng-model="term.tag"` Parent: `<select ng-model="main.the_tag.tag"`